# Javascript Pass Element ID Attribute as Parameter

Tags: javascript, onclick, parameter-passing, setattribute

This statement works. On the click of the node, i get a message displaying its ID.

```
 newnode.setAttribute("onClick", "alert(this.id)");
```

I need to pass the value of *this.id* to a different function and am struggling to get around it.

Attempt 1:

The below does not work; I understand that i cant pass **this.id** to another function, which does the same thing, because **this** is not relevant to anything within the test function:

```
newnode.setAttribute("onClick", "test(this.id)"); 

function test(f){
alert(f);
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
var testvar = newnode.id;
newnode.setAttribute("onClick", "test(testvar)"); 

function test(f){
alert(f);
}
```

Why is *testvar* not recognised in my setAttribute line?

Comment: If `alert(this.id)` works, then `test(this.id)` will work - `alert()` is just a function.

Comment: Be careful with functions within strings because you trigger `eval` there which is unnecessary 99% of the time.

Comment: Try this: `newnode.setAttribute("onClick", test(testvar));`

Comment: Also, assigning the click event as an attribute is not a very good idea. Just use `addEventListener` or `el.onclick = fn`. Notice too that `onclick` is typically all lowercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
newNode.onclick = function(){
  test(this.id);
};

function test(id){
  alert(id);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sHZeL/1/